# Binding The Frame Size With Its Objects Sizes

Tags: java, swing, resize, jframe

How to change the code below that after changing the frame size, the size of other objects on the frame changes with the same ratio too?

```
package application;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Program extends JFrame {

    private GroupLayout layout;
    private GroupLayout.Group groupX;
    private GroupLayout.Group groupY;

    public Program() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        this.layout = new GroupLayout(this.getContentPane());
        this.groupX = this.layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING);
        this.groupY = this.layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING);
    }

    public void addComponent(Component component, int x, int y) {

        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);

        groupX.addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(x, x, x)
                .addComponent(component, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE));

        groupY.addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(y, y, y)
                .addComponent(component, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE));    
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(groupX);
        layout.setVerticalGroup(groupY);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Program jf = new Program();
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setBounds(new Rectangle(0, 0, 250, 100));
        JButton p = new JButton("Click!!");
        jf.addComponent(p, 86, 20);
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

How to change the code below that after changing the frame size, the size of other objects on the frame changes with the same ratio too?

[image]

Comment: if I understand you correctly you want to zoom the ui? If so, that's not supported (and unrelated to the tasks of a LayoutManager) out of the box. You have to implement it yourself, f.i. using JLayer (jdk7) or JXLayer (jdk6)

Comment: No. I don't want to zoom the UI. I want to implement something just like anchor in C#, which means if I change the width of frame, the width of its objects change too.

Comment: okay, thanks for the clarification (but note that your image is misleading, as the font size is increased along with the button size which will not happen except when you zoom)

Answer (score 1):

I'd just like to say, I don't like `GroupLayout`, but that's just me :D

[image][image]

```
jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

jButton1.setText("jButton1");

javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
this.setLayout(layout);
layout.setHorizontalGroup(
  layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
  .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
    .addGap(152, 152, 152)
    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 143, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    .addGap(175, 175, 175))
);
layout.setVerticalGroup(
  layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
  .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
    .addGap(137, 137, 137)
    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    .addGap(94, 94, 94))
);
```

Comment: Simply modify the code to take x/y and width/height values instead

Comment: _I don't like GroupLayout_ me neither - but then, it is designed for usage in a builder, not for manual coding, so it's doing a good job in conveying the latter :-)

Answer (score -1):

```
Try using GridBagLayout which is easier.

private void initialize() {
    getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(new Rectangle(0, 0, 250, 100));
    JButton p = new JButton("Click!!");
    add(p, new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.5,
            GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST, GridBagConstraints.BOTH,
            new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5), 0, 0));
    setVisible(true);
}
```